# Java Enum - what's the difference between enum has override logic and enum abstract factory and each class has override logic?

Tags: java, design-patterns, enums

I'm trying to use enum more effeciently.

First question is If I use like below, Is it some kind of strategy pattern?
Caller side call like Type.get(0).isSkip()

```
public enum Type {
    TYPE_A(0) {
        @Override
        public boolean isSkip() {
            return true;
        }

    abstract public boolean isSkip();
```

Caller side call like

```
Type.get(0).isSkip()
```

And second question is recently I found enum abstract factory pattern like

```
interface IType {
    public boolean isSkip();
}

public class Type {
    class Type_A implements IType {
        public Type_A() {}
        @Override public boolean isSkip() {
        }
    }
}
```

and Enum class just do factory things like

```
interface IFactory
{
    public IType get();
};

public enum EnumAbstractFactory implements IFactory{
    A {
        public IType get() {
            return new Type_A();
        }
    }
```

What's the advantage of abstract factory method better then just Enum class has logic?
Which one is better solution?

Answer (score 1):

The first example is just a lookup. You could achieve the same with a `Map<Integer, Type>`. Occasionally this makes sense as a deserialization pattern, but more often it raises the question of why a client is passing [primitives](https://refactoring.guru/smells/primitive-obsession) to get polymorphic behavior.

In the second example, it is redundant to return a Type from an enum instance, because an enum instance already *is* a Type. In Java, the enum can do all of things the Type could do, so just move the Type-specific methods into the respective enum instance. You don't need to create a [parallel hierarchy](https://refactoring.guru/smells/parallel-inheritance-hierarchies).

In short, neither of these examples are good solutions.

Comment: Well as i know enum class put related constant variables together in one class. so it is recommended to use. but you said neither one is good. :( then what do you think best option to constant variables?

Answer (score 1):

I find it hard to follow why you'd use either form in the manner you've stated for use as "abstract factory" - it would help if you edit the question with more details as the code you have suggests it is determining some "isSkip()" capability of a type.

The first form is not a very readable way to declare an enum: The `@Override isSkip()` causes an unnecessary new anonymous class, and you can't derive classes from the enum so the `abstract public boolean isSkip()` declaration is pointless.

As an alternative I'd suggest a concise definition which sets up `isSkip` capability as constructor parameter, or with a map of enums, or with method `isSkip()` as below:

```
enum Type {
    TYPE_A, TYPE_B, TYPE_C; // etc
    public boolean isSkip() {
        return this == TYPE_A;
    };
}
```

This way you can reference with `Type.XYZ.isSkip()`. You can also use the `IType` interface on the enum as below if there are other classes you need to share this `isSkip` capability:

```
enum Type  implements IType {
...
}
```